# How to call methods from the parent component in child in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, parent-child

I have a click event and with this click event I want to call function/methods which is in parent component. So the click event in my child component:

```
 <button @click.native="addNew" />
```

Here is my method:

```
methods: {
    addNew() {
      this.$parent.addNew();
    },
  },
```

Ad I want to call this function in my parent component:

```
addNew() {
      this.$emit('open');
    },
```

But I a getting an error like: this.$parent.addNew is not a function. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on $emit event in Vue.js: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

When you emit an event like this: $emit('someEvent'), the parent `someEvent` function will fire (and also you can pass some parameters).

So you must listen to the 'someEvent' function in parent.

EDIT: this link would be a good example: https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-emit-guide

Comment: So you say here methods: {
    addNew() {
      this.$parent.addNew();
    },
  }, I should add emit but how can I listen that? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @World'sfamouspeople I made an edit to the post which I provided and example to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example working with events

Child.vue

```html
<template>
 <button @click="$emit('childClick')">click me</button>
</template>
```

Parent.vue

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'
  function onChildClick(){
    console.log("child has clicked")
  }
</script>

<template>
  <Child @childClick="onChildClick"></Child>
</template>
```